# query that only returns records from one table that sit outside of a time range in another table

Tags: sql

firstly, thanks for looking at this and with any help getting my head round this problem

I have a table below which records a few bits of data from computers, with a timestamp. There is a journey table (joining on `computer_id`) that links it with a journey details table, which has a start and end timestamp (joining on `journey_id`).

I am trying to create a query which will return only the records in the telemetry table that:

- **don't** sit within the `start_timestamp` and `end_timestamp` in the journey details table, for that matching `computer_id`. i.e. illegitimate telemetry records
- this would be limited to results from the last 3 days based on the telemetry table

The schema cannot be changed and I'd be using standard SQL / bigquery

**telemetry table**

```
+-------------+-------------+------------------+
| computer_id | temperature | timestamp        |
+-------------+-------------+------------------+
| a123        | 20          | 23/01/2020 01:01 |
| a123        | 20          | 23/01/2020 01:02 |
| a123        | 20          | 23/01/2020 01:03 |
| a123        | 25          | 22/01/2020 06:01 |
| a123        | 25          | 22/01/2020 06:02 |
| a123        | 25          | 22/01/2020 06:03 |
| a123        | 15          | 18/01/2020 00:01 |
+-------------+-------------+------------------+
```

**journey table**

```
+------------+-------------+------------+
| journey_id | computer_id | company_id |
+------------+-------------+------------+
| 1          | a123        | bigcorp    |
| 2          | a123        | bigcorp    |
+------------+-------------+------------+
```

**journey details table**

```
+--------------------+------------+------------------+------------------+
| journey_details_id | journey_id | start_timestamp  | end_timestamp    |
+--------------------+------------+------------------+------------------+
| 1                  | 1          | 23/01/2020 01:00 | 23/01/2020 01:04 |
| 2                  | 2          | 22/01/2020 07:00 | 22/01/2020 07:03 |
+--------------------+------------+------------------+------------------+
```

**[result] filtered telemetry table**, assuming executed 24/01/20 at 00:00:00

```
+-------------+-------------+------------------+
| computer_id | temperature | timestamp        |
+-------------+-------------+------------------+
| a123        | 25          | 22/01/2020 06:01 |
| a123        | 25          | 22/01/2020 06:02 |
| a123        | 25          | 22/01/2020 06:03 |
+-------------+-------------+------------------+
```

so far, I have:

```
SELECT a.computer_id, a.temperature, a.timestamp, b.journey_id, c.journey_id
FROM `telemetry` as a
INNER JOIN `journey` as b ON b.computer_id = a.computer_id
INNER JOIN `journey_details` as c ON c.journey_id = b.journey_id
WHERE DATE(a.time) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(current_date(), INTERVAL 3 DAY) AND current_date()
AND
DATE(a.timestamp) NOT BETWEEN DATE(c.start_timestamp) AND CASE WHEN DATE(c.end_timestamp) IS NULL THEN current_date() ELSE DATE(c.end_timestamp) END
ORDER BY
a.time DESC
LIMIT 100
```

The desired result from the above query would mean that the results returned would have `journey_id` in tables journey and journey_details as null, since there wouldn't be any matching journeys if the timestamp fell outside of `start_time` and `end_time`. If there were no matching `computer_id` in `journey` it would also return it, since these telemetry points are also illigitimate!

Perhaps using an OUTER join to journey_detail would be better? I am a newbie at SQL so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`NOT EXISTS` comes to mind:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM telemetry t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM journey j AND
                       journey_details jd 
                       ON jd.journey_id = j.journey_id
                  WHERE j.computer_id = t.computer_id AND
                        t.timestamp <= c.end_timestamp AND
                        t.timestamp >= c.start_timestamp
                 ) AND
      t.timestamp >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 DAY
ORDER BY t.timestamp DESC
LIMIT 100
```